# After execvp returns, why doesn't my program pick up where it left off?

Tags: c, multithreading, execvp

I have a block of code like this that runs as a child thread:

```
if(someVar == 1){
doSomeStuff;

_exit(0)
}
else
   execvp(*(temp->_arguments), temp->_arguments);
printf("I'm done\n");
```

When I run the program with someVar == 1, I understand that the _exit(0) call kills my thread. However, when it's set to 0, why doesn't the program continue after the execvp() call and do the printf statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you [`exec*`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) (call any exec function from the exec family), then the code of a new program is loaded into your current process and execution continues with its main function and its stuff. On a successful execution of those functions, they will never return because your `printf` does not exist anymore in memory.

I think you confuse `exec*` with the [`fork`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) function. That will splice off a new child process which will run the same code as the parent.

If what you want is to create a new thread, that shares data and the address space with the main thread, you should use the [`pthread_create`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) function. A new process will not share data and you will have to communicate with the other process using other mechanisms, like pipes or shared memory.

Answer (score 2):

[execvp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) overwrites your program with the new executable and doesn't return, unless an error occurs. You need to [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) first and then call exec* on the child process.

Answer (score 2):

because `execvp` *replaces* the process you *were* running with the process you *exec*'ed.  If *execvp* returns, it's because it failed.  It shouldn't return otherwise.