# Set environment variables in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, environment-variables

Is there a way to set environment variables in Linux using C?

I tried `setenv()` and `putenv()`, but they don't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Why do you think they didn't work?  (That is, how did you test this?  getenv?)

Comment: Could you post a code sample and a demo showing how they don't work?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'm going to make a wild guess here, but the normal reason that these functions appear to not work is not because they don't work, but because the user doesn't really understand how environment variables work.  For example, if I have this program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  putenv("SomeVariable=SomeValue");
  return 0;
}
```

And then I run it from the shell, it won't modify the shell's environment - there's no way for a child process to do that.  That's why the shell commands that modify the environment are builtins, and why you need to `source` a script that contains variable settings you want to add to your shell, rather than simply running it.

Comment: The corollary to this is to get the "run program to set variables" behavior in the shell you 1) write a shell script to do the job and 2) don't run it the usual way, but rather `source` it. (BTW in most shells `. script` is the same as `source script` and a lot less typing.)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you :) Yeah, that was what I was doing. I'm new to linux, so pardon me if this is a stupid question, but is there no way at all for a child process to set the shells environment in C, and by not sourcing a script. I'm interning at this company and I've been asked to write a function to set the timezone of a device running linux, so I was trying to set the TZ environment of the shell.

Comment: @iman: try `man -k tz` for some options. On my Mac OS X machine what shows up is `tzset (3)`...

Comment: @dmckee: wouldn't tzset still work only for the process I run the code and all its child processes? I sorta wanted a way such that all the processes get this information (don't know if that's even possible lol)

Comment: @iman: Yes. That advice appears to have been worth every cent you paid for it. Sorry.

Comment: @iman453, you should be able to write a shell script to do what you'd like.

Answer (score 13):

Any unix program runs in a separate process from the process which starts it; this is a 'child' process.

When a program is started up -- be that at the command line or any other way -- the system creates a new process which is (more-or-less) a copy of the parent process.  That copy includes the environment variables in the parent process, and this is the mechanism by which the child process 'inherits' the environment variables of its parent.  (this is all largely what other answers here have said)

That is, a process only *ever* sets its *own* environment variables.

Others have mentioned sourcing a shell script, as a way of setting environment variables in the current process, but if you need to set variables in the current (shell) process programmatically, then there is a slightly indirect way that it's possible.

Consider this:

```
% cat envs.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("ENV%d=%s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
}
% echo $ENV1

% ./envs one two
ENV1=one
ENV2=two
% eval `./envs one two`
% echo $ENV1
one
%
```

The built-in `eval` evaluates its argument as if that argument were typed at the shell prompt.  This is a sh-style example; the csh-style variant is left as an exercise!

Comment: I noticed this was down-voted.  Any indication why?  Did someone spot an error?

Comment: Not sure why someone would downvote this. Weird. Looks like a good solution to me!

Comment: I suppose it's because the answer sets the environment variable using the built-in bash command 'eval', which are the chances that the programmer might not be able to use bash at all. If the programmer is allowed to use a shell script (which is not always the case, hence the question), there're other more obvious and better ways to set the environment variable other than the bash specific eval. (p.s. I didn't downvote)

Comment: What are the other ways you're thinking of? It's true that the question is a little vague, but I took/take it to be asking how one would set environment variables in a shell, using a program. Since the only ways I can think of that the variables can be set _in that shell_ are using `source` or `eval`, there are few options (of course, if you want them to be set in the current or a child process, then you just use `setenv`). Note that `eval` isn't just bash – it's in [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#eval); I don't know what the *csh equivalent is.

Answer (score 8):

The environment variable set by setenv()/putenv() will be set for the process that executed these functions and will be inherited by the processes launched by it. However, it will not be *broadcasted* into the shell that executed your program.

[Why isn't my wrapper around setenv() working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662466/why-isnt-my-wrapper-around-setenv-working/662486#662486)

Answer (score 1):

The environment block is process-local, and copied to child processes.  So if you change variables, the new value only affects your process and child processes spawned after the change.  Assuredly it will not change the shell you launched from.

Answer (score 0):

**Not** an answer to this question, just wanna say that `putenv` is dangerous, use `setenv` instead.

`putenv(char *string)` is dangerous for the reason that all it does is simply append the address of your key-value pair string to the  `environ` array. Therefore, if we subsequently modify the bytes pointed to by `string`, the change will affect the process environment.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char new_env[] = "A=A";
    putenv(new_env);

    // modifying your `new_env` also modifies the environment
    // vairable
    new_env[0] = 'B';
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Since `environ` only stores the address of our `string` argument, `string` has to be static to prevent the dangling pointer.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo();

int main(void) {
    foo();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void foo() {
    char new_env[] = "A=B";
    putenv(new_env);
}
```

When the stack frame for `foo` function is deallocated, the bytes of `new_env` are gone, and the address stored in `environ` becomes a dangling pointer.

Comment: More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873029/questions-about-putenv-and-setenv)