# linux function setenv and putenv

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions about putenv() and setenv()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873029/questions-about-putenv-and-setenv)

As we know,we can use function **setenv** and **putenv** to change environment variables.What are their differences? Do they need to allocate memory or not?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From `setenv`'s [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv):

> The  `setenv()`  function  adds  the variable name to the environment with the value value, if name does not already exist.  If name does exist in the environment, then its value is changed to value if overwrite is nonzero; if overwrite is zero, then the value of name is not changed.  This function makes copies of the strings  pointed  to  by  name  and  value  (by  contrast  with `putenv(3)`).

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876818/1984421).