In the C++ standard why is getenv defined but not setenv?
Can't seem to find the definition of setenv or something similar in the standard.
whereas getenv seems to be there and is available portably in both windows and posix standard libraries.
In short is there a reason or discussion as to why this might be?

You're looking for putenv. However, I believe this is a POSIX function, is nonstandard and may be deprecated. If I had to guess as to why it's not standard, I'd say it's because different operating systems could have their own rules about modifying the environment of a running process. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873029/questions-about-putenv-and-setenv

so I'm presuming there's no std defined portable way and that i'll need to ifdef an implementation for each OS, would that be accurate?

Probably, or change your design so that you don't need to modify the environment (e.g. spawn child process with new environment). Practicality depends highly on how many operating systems you need to support. Often people fixate on "portable" code, yet they only ever plan to run it on at most the big three: Linux, Mac, Windows.

was actually trying to write a unit test for an answer i've just given and found the windows builds fail when i run it through CI. might need to rework things a little.

@paddy man putenv on my Arch Linux system doesn't say anything about the function being deprecated.

man putenv on my system says: The getenv() function conforms to ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (“ISO C90”).  The setenv(), putenv() and unsetenv() functions conforms to IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (“POSIX.1”).

I had no idea getenv was part of the standard!  Learn something new every day.

getenv() is useful
You can use it to get environmental data as input to your program. This is the primary purpose of the shell’s environment table — provide a way for the user to modify the behavior of system programs.
For example, on Linux, the $LS_COLORS environment variable is a way to modify the colors used to display directory information using the ls (list directory) program. Every user can set his or her own preferred color scheme to use when displaying a file listing with ls, even though ls is a system program.
putenv() is not useful (generally)
A program may modify its environment table, but it cannot modify the environment table of other programs, such as the parent shell! This is by design, and is a security feature.
Both *nixen and Windows have functions that do allow you to add or modify variables in the current process’s environment table. This is useful when spawning a child process, which can be explicitly initialized to inherit the current process’s environment table. But such behavior is largely a specialized need, so there is no good argument to make such a function part of the C Standard.
It used to be possible to sneakily modify other processes’ environment tables on Windows, assuming you had sufficient permissions to do so, but such behavior has been made much more difficult since XP or so.

I disagree with "putenv() is not useful" here.

How do you know the commenter is the one who downvoted? This is so common, it drives me nuts. I often comment on a post providing some kind of critical feedback, then not vote at all, but because I'm the one who made a comment which roughly coincided with the timing of when a person learned there was a comment and a downvote, suddenly I'm the bad guy. It would pay to keep this in mind before jumping to conclusions. Actually, any kind of complaining about downvotes is bad taste. We've all done it. I've certainly done it. Then I realized what a bad look it is.

I will add that it takes 5 downvotes to negate one upvote. If you're concerned about increasing rep, then that's your yardstick. If your net reputation gain is -10 or less, take that as a glaring sign of a content issue, not a community issue. Anything less than that should be either ignored as entropy, or considered as feedback on some need to improve the answer. RIght now your votes are +1/-1 so your net rep is +8, and was possibly -2 at some point. I don't see the issue.
