# setting environment variable using setenv

Tags: c, linux

I want to set and get the value of environment variable in Linux using C. Can anyone tell me how to use the `setenv` environment variable.

I want the environment value to be set to zero, and while using the `getenv` that environment value should be `0`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set environment variables in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416638/set-environment-variables-in-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416638/set-environment-variables-in-c

Comment: There may be two different things called `setenv`, a shell command (available only if you're using csh or tcsh; other shells generally use `set` and `export` for the same purpose) and a C library function (whose man page you should read before trying to use it). See also `putenv()`.

Comment: @ChrisCleeland i mean the value zero

Answer (score 2):

Try to use putenv() instead of setenv(). A little substrac of the manpage says:

"The setenv() function inserts or resets the environment variable name in the current environment list. If the variable name does not exist in the list, it is inserted with the given value. If the variable does exist, the argument overwrite is tested; **if overwrite is zero, the variable is not reset, otherwise it is reset to the given value.**"

A question, when you said zero, you are talking about zero character right?. You have to put a string there.

Comment: I dont know how you are going to use it. But if you expect to use the environment variable after program execution in another program or in console, it is not going to work because you are in another session. The visibility of a EV is from the parent to child processes.