# Programmatically LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c++, c, linux

Currently, I have an application that does:

`execlp(java_exec, java_args, etc, etc);`

to launch a jar file.

Is there a way to also have it prepend `LD_PRELOAD="mylib.so"` ?

I couldn't find a way to tell `execlp` to do:  `LD_PRELOAD="mylib.so" java -jar foo.jar`

Any ideas how I can achieve this in C or C++ on Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416638/set-environment-variables-in-c

Comment: Can you not just use `putenv` from the  C library before calling `execlp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command can be used to append the user .so in LD_PRELOAD variable
  `set LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD;"mylib.so"` 
 System command can be used to set this from C file

Comment: Just a note: Moving from using `exec*()` to `system()` is probably not a good idea, as there are good reasons to use exec instead of system in a program.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably add `LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so` to `*envp`, `execlpe()`'s fourth arg.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you could use [putenv(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html) (perhaps with [snprintf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) or [asprintf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) ...) before [execlp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execlp.3.html). for example:

```
char buf[64];
memset (buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
snprintf (buf, sizeof(buf), "LD_PRELOAD=%s", yourlibso);
putenv(buf);
```

and after that your `execlp`....

However, both `putenv` and `snprintf` could fail (or have weird behavior, if `yourlibso`  happens to contain a *long* string).

You might test before that `yourlibso` is good enough with [access(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) or [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).

Handling every failure is difficult.

See [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/errno.2.html).

Things are much simpler when `yourlibso` is known at compile-time. See a draft C standard such as [n2573](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2573.pdf), or a draft C++ standard such as [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

> Any ideas how I can achieve this in C or C++ on Linux?

#### remember that C and C++ are different programming languages.